# Uncaught Error: Class 'Knp\Snappy\Pdf' not found

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I have local Apache2.4 on window 10 with php 7.2.4 version.
When I send my html form to the server, I get
Uncaught Error: Class 'Knp\Snappy\Pdf' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\bitul-rishum\pdf.php:15
The pdf.php is:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (!isset($_POST['html']) || empty($_POST['html'])) {
   echo 'No no no!!! ))))';
   return;
}
$dir = __DIR__;
require_once $dir . '/../httpdocs/vendor/autoload.php';
// $path = '/var/www/vhosts/5.automas.co.il/4.automas.co.il/public/upload/';
$path = '/public/upload/';
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

$snappy = new Pdf('C://"Program Files"/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe');

ob_start();
?>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he-IL">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>בקשת העברה למסגרת אחרת - בתי ספר - מחלקת החינוך</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main><!-- main[white-bg] -->
           <?php echo str_replace("https://tk.bitul-rishum.automas.co.il", $dir, $_POST['html']);?>
        </main>
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $('select').each(function(){
          $(this).replaceWith('<span style="    border-bottom: 1px solid #000; display: inline-block; height: 27px; margin-bottom: 5px;" class="text">'+$(this).val()+'</span>');
      });
  </script>
$snappy->setOption('page-size', 'A4');
$snappy->setOption('zoom', '1');
$snappy->setOption('margin-top', '0');
$snappy->setOption('margin-right', '0');
$snappy->setOption('margin-bottom', '0');
$snappy->setOption('margin-left', '0');
$pdfname = uniqid().'_'.time().'.pdf';

$snappy->generateFromHtml($html, $path .$pdfname);

if (file_exists($path.$pdfname)) {
echo $pdfname;
} else {
echo "error";
}
die();
```

I get the "Uncaught Error: Class 'Knp\Snappy\Pdf' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\bitul-rishum\pdf.php:15" message in http response of the post request that made from main.js.

I try to reinstall snappy by "composer require knplabs/knp-snappy", and it failed, saying:
..... can only install on of:....
and the last is:

```
Can only install one of: symfony/process[v5.0.4, v4.2.4].
Installation request for symfony/process (locked at v4.2.4) -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.2.4].
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

when I type:
`PS C:\Apache24\htdocs\httpdocs\vendor> composer global why symfony/process -t`
I get:

```
Changed current directory to C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Composer
symfony/process v4.4.3 Symfony Process Component
└──laravel/installer v1.5.0 (requires symfony/process ~3.0|~4.0)
└──__root__ (requires laravel/installer ~1.1)
```

## composer.json:

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.4",
        "consoletvs/charts": "6.*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.24"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Please help,
Menachem

Comment: Did you install any package providing the PDF classes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Laravel ?
Why not to use laravel-snappy

To use snappy-laravel you need to follow the instructions here
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy , or below I tried to make them easier to read and follow :

`1. Download wkhtmltopdf from here https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html`

`2. Package Installation: composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy`

`3. In (app.php) providers array add  Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider::class,`

`4. In (app.php) aliases array add   'PDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class, 'SnappyImage' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class,`

`5. Run php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider"`

`6. In (snappy.php) edit the binary path based on your installation path for wkhtmltopdf For me it is the following :` 
return array(

```
'pdf' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    // base_path('vendor\wemersonjanuario\wkhtmltopdf-windows\bin\64bit\wkhtmltopdf'),
    'binary'  =>'"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf"',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => array(),
    'env'     => array(),
),
'image' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  =>'"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf"',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => array(),
    'env'     => array(),

    
),
```

);